# How to use Azure B2C Company Branding in Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Azure AD B2C allows configuring "Company branding" in the UI. I can upload a Banner Logo, Background Image, etc.

**However, when using a custom IEF policy, is there a way to reference the uploaded resources in the custom policy?**

Here is an example of the reference in a default B2C HTML template:

```
<img class="companyLogo" data-tenant-branding-logo="true" src="https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/templates/images/logo.svg" alt="Company Logo">
```

If I look at the built in user flows and how they reference the image, there is a very complex URL:

```
<img class="companyLogo" data-tenant-branding-logo="true" src="https://aadcdn.msftauthimages.net/dbd6a2dd-0-ioujrdaqa9-fuefw74nl6mc2sieecnt6keujpvcwy/logintenantbranding/0/bannerlogo?ts=638528323204335100" alt="Company Logo">
```

I know I can upload the resource to a static storage account and reference the URL directly, and I could probably reference the complex URL shown in the built in flow above. But, is there a supported, straight forward method to accomplish what I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it doesn't matter what you put in the Image URL of the custom HTML. The key is to use the following HTML attributes to enable custom branding inside the custom HTML:

```
<img data-tenant-branding-background="true" />
<img data-tenant-branding-logo="true" alt="Company Logo" />
```

It is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#use-company-branding-assets-in-custom-html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use custom html templates you can just migrate the `DataUri` nodes to page layout in your `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` file as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-company-branding-in-custom-policy-pages